# allowed-dates attribute in Vuetify date picker is not responsive

Tags: vue.js, date, datepicker, calendar, vuetify.js

I have a web page that displays a Vuetify date-picker component.

When the page is loaded or when the month is changed, I make an AJAX call that runs an SQL query to return the dates in that specific month when a particular event occurred.

Then, I only want to make these specific dates clickable.

As per the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#allowed-dates), the allowed-dates attribute allows you to do this.

After some experimentation, I have come across some unexpected difficulty:

- The allowed-dates attribute takes in a function instead of, for example, an array. So, I had to create a function that will consult an "allowed dates" array that is returned by my AJAX call
- Furthermore, the function is called when the date-picker is rendered and NOT when the AJAX call returns, so I end up with no dates being activated or only one date being activated on only the last date of the month being activated.

Am I missing something? is the allowed-dates attribute not responsive? I would prefer to stick with Vuetify since I am using it for the rest of the UI, but I am willing to switch to something else if a solution cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some confution when an example in docs says:

> You can specify allowed dates using arrays, objects, and functions.

But in API `allowed-dates` consumes only functions.

---

I guess the answer is to correctly define **allowedDates** function.

You first need to create an empty reactive array, then assign data into it via AJAX call, and in **allowedDates** function you just be able to compare the displayed page of dates with the dates in the array.

So the code is...

```js
<v-date-picker
  v-model="date"
  :allowed-dates="allowedDates"
/>

...

data: () => ({
  date: '2022-01-11',
  allowedDatesArray: [],
}),
mounted() {
  this.getAllowedDates();
},
methods: {
  allowedDates(val) {
    return this.allowedDatesArray.includes(val);
  },
  async getAllowedDates() {
    this.allowedDatesArray = [];
    await //...your AJAX call that must assign allowedDatesArray
  }
}
```

I created [a sandbox at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/QWqZQOw) where you may test this solution with some static dates that loading asynchronously using `Promise`.

In your solution you need to replace `Promise` with your AJAX call.