# Set Vuetify Datepicker allowed-dates range after mount

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm wanting to pass through an array of allowed dates into my Datepicker as follows:

HTML:

```
 <v-date-picker
          
                v-model="dates"
                :allowed-dates="disabledDates"
              >
</v-date-picker>
```

JavaScript:

```
disabledDates: val =>

this.bookingDates.indexOf(val) === -1,
```

However the disabledDates method is being called when the Datepicker is rendered (before mount) and thus this.bookingDates does not exist yet. Is there a way to render the Datepicker only after the this.bookingDates array has been populated?

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658969/allowed-dates-attribute-in-vuetify-date-picker-is-not-responsive

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I currently have my code structured like this but it's still the same issue. The getAllowedDates() method is what populates the bookingDates array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, better correct the function name "disabledDates" by "allowedDates".
Then the function will be like:

```
allowedDates: dt => ['2023-03-17', '2023-03-22'].indexOf(dt.toString('yyyy-mm-dd')) >= 0,
```

[image]

To block all dates before "today":

```
allowedDates: dt => dt >= new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10),
```

[image]

I hope it helps ;)